# Gupshup whatsApp api sends 'ok' message on returning 200 after receiving webhook

Tags: node.js, gupshup

I am using nodejs for backend. I am able to receive webhooks from Gupshup api. After receiving webhook, I am responding with status 200.

```
res.sendStatus(200);
```

Gupshup whatsApp api sends 'ok' message to user on returning 200 after receiving webhook automatically.

[image]

Here ok is not message by outbound api. Rather its automatically responded by Gupshup api.

Comment: so what is the issue ?

Comment: Ok is not outbound message. Rather its automatically sent by Gupshup whatsApp api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of,

```
res.sendStatus(200) // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')
```

You should send a nil response.

```
 res.end()
```

*The OK is forwarded by gupshup to the user as a message*